# how to secure android and angularJS using REST API services spring boot backend

Tags: android, angularjs, spring, rest, oauth

I have a project, angularjs webapp (backend java and spring boot) and uses google map too, there is an android app that sends alerts to this webapp and those show location on the webapp’s map. However when I implement spring security it would secure the webapp and REST api, but will prevent the alerts from android showing on the map (can not find resource)….

I want an easy simple way to secure the app without stopping the REST API services, yes I want to secure my API but still want to be able to show the alerts sent from android device, also still accepts new registration from android users....(android users cant access webapp they only register to use android app and will be added to database..they will need to be able to post their info...)

I tried oauth2 using google sing in, but I must be missing something as it wont load,..If you think this is the right approach please confirm...I will further look into it...Or direct me to tutorial or give me any suggestions...

P.S I am using bluemix platform as a service at the moment and CLearDB database service from bluemix

I am a student and all this is new to me...Thanks